# Using Intuit-partner-platform for my company

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I'm interested in using the intuit-partner-platform rest API to automatically generate invoices into our QuickBooks Online account, from an in house database.  Although it would be interesting to eventually create an application that I could sell to other parties, I'm mainly trying to get my feet wet with this specific internal need.

Is there any problem with using the Intuit-partner-platform in this way?

Would my company be able to continue to use this application even if it is not sold to other consumers?

Comment: The short answer is: no, you can't use IPP. The longer answer is: you CAN, however, use the SDK instead.

Answer (score 3):

IPP Intuit Anywhere is the new platform only for **SaaS applications**.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq#What_types_of_applications_are_supported_with_QuickBooks_API.3F

Dev docs - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started

**QBO** API docs - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online

Intuit still provides the traditional **QBSDK SDK** v12, which is useful if you are creating a **custom integration for one company**, or focused entirely on desktop scenarios only.

QBSDK Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb

Thanks